# Navigation Drawer with webview auto-closes after scrolling

Tags: android

I've put a webview on the Navigation Drawer; the webview shows formatted text about the current UI so that the users can familiarize themselves with features.

Unfortunately, after scrolling up or down on the webview (horizontal scrolling of the webview is disabled), the navigation drawer closes itself after I lift my finger off the webview !

How can I prevent the Navigation Drawer from closing itself when the user lets go ?

EDIT:
additional findings ... I've attached an OnTouchListener() to the drawer's layout that does nothing except return true. This prevents the auto-closing from happening when touching an empty space on the Navigation Drawer. To see how this is done, check out http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/01/android-drawerlayout-and-drawerlistener.html and look at the "experimental" comment.

**Unfortunately** it doesn't stop the Navigation Drawer from closing when the user doesn't scroll up/down perfectly on the webview.
For example, scrolling up and down on the webview will close the drawer if there is a very small horizontal component to the drag.

Answer (score -1):

So the (hassle-free) solution to prevent the over-zealous closing of the drawer: once the drawer is open, lock it open and have a button trigger the closeDrawer(). The code below shows how to manage the lock/unlock status. It doesn't include the button to call closeDrawer() because that's quite basic.

in XML, the id of the DrawerLayout is :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

in your Activity, the java code is :

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutwithdrawer);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
        // allow swiping to open the drawer
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
        // disable swiping so that the drawer can't be closed by accident when scrolling through webview
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {}

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {}
}
```