# How do I prevent Navigation Drawer to close accidentally while I try to scroll a list inside it?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout in my activty and navigation drawer occupies 3/4th of the screen width. The drawer has a recycleview which gets populated using some adapater. Now the problem is that when I try to scroll the recycleview then sometimes DrawerLayout steals the event and close the drawer instead of scrolling the recycleview. This is making drawer to get close accidentally. How do I prevent this from happening. Ideally I don't want DrawerLayout to respond to touch events as long as it is happening upon recycleview.

activity.xml  -

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/retail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/DrawerArrowStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/refreshingProgressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:contentDescription="Loading..."
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/new_wishlist_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: try to check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392300/navigation-drawer-with-webview-auto-closes-after-scrolling

Comment: paste some code ? (Main-activity xml file )

Comment: Where's the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @alexey polusov - Your solution completely locks the navigation drawer when it is opened. This is not what I have desired. I want the navigation drawer to be still interactive when dragged from outside the content area.

Comment: @Mike - I add a fragment inside android.support.design.widget.NavigationView programatically which has a recycleview.

Comment: You're transacting a `Fragment` into a `NavigationView`? That's, um, unusual. I would suggest that you temporarily replace the `NavigationView` with a basic `ViewGroup` - e.g., a `FrameLayout` - and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: Yes it is the same. I think DrawerLayout is intercepting ACTION_MOVE and I somehow have to stop it from doing that.

Comment: It really shouldn't be when the drawer's open, if you've done the `FragmentTransaction` correctly. I mean, you're transacting the Fragment into `R.id.new_wishlist_drawer`, yeah? Does your drawer work as expected without the `Fragment`? Maybe with just the `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this today, and came up with this solution:

```
public class LockableDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {
private long earliestEvent = -1;

public LockableDrawerLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public LockableDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public LockableDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void lockUntil(long delay) {
    this.earliestEvent = System.currentTimeMillis() + delay;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > earliestEvent) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

From the view with scroll, call lockUntil and the drawerlayout will be locked for the given delay.